# Can’t dynamically setState in React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can setState in react with a string as so:

```html
  return(
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={        
        () => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
              return {["mostPopContentCount"]: prevState["mostPopContentCount"] + 10}
            })
        }
    }>
      Load 10 more rows
    </a>  
  )
```

But if I want the key to be dynamic it won’t compile.

```html
  let name:string = "mostPopContentCount";

  return(
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={        
        () => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
              return {[name]: prevState[name] + 10}
            })
        }
    }>
      Load 10 more rows
    </a>  
  )
```

Comment: [How to use snippet tool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of ts, dont see the type of the state and dont recognize the key exists. You have to create a copy with a type:any,

```
  return(
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={        
        () => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
              let stateCopy:any={...prevState};
              stateCopy[name]: stateCopy[name] + 10
              return {stateCopy}
            })
        }
    }>
      Load 10 more rows
    </a>  
  )
```

Comment: You can difine a type for your prevState aswell.
this.setState((prevState:any) => {

Comment: yes tried that -  Argument of type '(prevState: any) => { stateCopy: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type

Comment: Seems to work with "return stateCopy" instead of destructed?

Comment: Yes, return only with the stateCopy, and the new state will be the stateCopy.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are missing something 
This works

```
render() {
console.log(this.state.mostPopContentCount);
const name = "mostPopContentCount";
return (
  <a
    href="javascript:void(0)"
    onClick={() => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return { [name]: prevState[name] + 10 };
      });
    }}
  >
    Load 10 more rows
  </a>
);
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-mountain-wipuw) this is not using typescript,
If it doesn't help you please create a sandbox so it's easy to debug

Hope it helps